# List of list increment if exists otherwise extend

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists as follows

```
[
['a', 1],
['b',2],
['c',1],
['a', 2],
['c', 5]
]
```

I want to normalize this list in such a way that for every, 'a', 'b', 'c' etc, I have only one unique entry in the list, and for every duplicate list, the second value which is the quantity is added so that I get something like:

```
[
['a', 3], # so since 'a' already existed the quantity is added 1 + 2 becomes 3
['b',2],
['c',6]   # similarly for 'c' it becomes 1 + 5 = 6
]
```

How to do this with Python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [
['a', 1],
['b',2],
['c',1],
['a', 2],
['c', 5]
]

d = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in l:
    d[key] += value

print(d.items())
```

Output:

```
dict_items([('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('c', 6)])
```

---

Also you can use a `try...expect` instead of `collections.defaultdict()`...if you'd like:

```
d = {}
for key, value in l:
    try:
        d[key] += value
    except KeyError:
        d[key] = value
```

---

Also, you can try `if...else`:

```
d = {}
for key, value in l:
    if key in d:
        d[key] += value
    else:
        d[key] = value
```

Comment: It is also possible to add a condition like **if key in d:** in case you don't want to use try except block.

Comment: @Rockybilly: Ah yeah, but I'd strongly recommend `defaultdict` anyways. And that would be slow than `try...expect`.

Comment: Me too, just suggested that instead of try..except.

Answer (score 1):

here is a long way to do it, but returns a list, not a data object

```
def normalizelist(inp):
 out=[]
 for key,count in inp:
  exist=0
  for place, val in enumerate(out):
   if (key==val[0]):
    out[place][1]+=count
    exist=1        #found it, so don't need to make it
    break          #no need to go further
  if (exist==0):   #didn't find it, therefor it needs to be added
   out.append([key,count])
 return out
```

hopefully that helps!

Comment: Actually the output of my answer *is* a list, if you want see a real list just use `list(d.items())`.

Comment: idk, what I did makes more sense to me